# ADB shell commands on one line / bash script?

Tags: android, bash, shell

For most ADB commands, I understand how to run them on a single line or even when placing them in a shell script, it can easily be done by implementing the secondary command after 'adb shell' but adding " ".

But for some reason nothing works on trying to run this command via a single line or even by putting it in a shell script:

```
adb shell 
task_id=$(dumpsys activity | grep -A2 "(dumpsys activity recents)"| grep '#'| cut -d ' ' -f 7| cut -c 2-); am task lock $task_id
```

Btw, this is to "screen pin" an application on Android devices.

Comment: does it give an error message, and what is the error message ?

Comment: In addition to any error messages, you should also mention whether you're running the `adb` command on Linux, Mac, or Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes around your commands :

```
adb shell '
task_id=$(dumpsys activity | grep -A2 "(dumpsys activity recents)"| grep "#"| cut -d " " -f 7| cut -c 2-)
echo "locking task $task_id"
am task lock $task_id
'
```

or on one line:

```
adb shell 'task_id=$(dumpsys activity | grep -A2 "(dumpsys activity recents)"| grep "#"| cut -d " " -f 7| cut -c 2-); am task lock $task_id'
```

Comment: omg... I thought I tried that. lol. I think I accidentally used double quotes instead. wow I'm dumb. lol. But thank you!

Comment: I just tried to activate skiagl with `adb shell 'su;setprop debug.hwui.renderer skiagl;stop;start'` , see doc here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#skia-emulator 

i never get the command line back