# How to execute commands inside adb shell for she'll script

Tags: bash, shell, adb

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
adb shell wpa_cli list_n all
sleep 2
echo 
adb shell am broadcast -a amazon.speech.ROUTE_DIRECTIVE --es directive '{"directive": {"header": {"namespace": "Alexa.Networking.WiFi","name": "GetProfiles","messageId": "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426652350006","correlationToken": "1234"},"payload": {}}}'
sleep 80
echo 
adb shell logcat -v time -b all | grep -i "getprofile"
sleep 10
```

..the command which starts from "am broadcast" should be given inside adb shell. Then only it's giving the exact output. Rather if i use the command out side the adb shell like "adb shell am broadcast" then it's not working. Could you please help me

Comment: Consider feeding the code to run on stdin; that way you can use a heredoc.

Comment: Please help me to get execute the command  inside and shell. Output should be like "Get profiles succeeded"

Comment: Consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44769454/17856705) for a similar problem.